# Quarkus, Keycloak and OIDC token refresh

Tags: jwt, keycloak, openid-connect, quarkus

I’m currently working on a PoC with multiple Quarkus services and Keycloak RBAC. Works like a charm, easily to bootstrap and start implementing features.

But I encountered an issue that I could not solve in my mind. Imagine:

1. User accesses a protected service
2. `quarkus-oidc` extension does fancy token obtaining by HTTP redirecting, JWT in cookie lasts 30 minutes
3. User is authenticated and gets returned to the web application
4. User works in application, fills in forms and data
5. Data is being stored by JWT-enriched REST calls (we do validation by `hibernate-validator`)
6. User works again, taking longer than 30 min
7. Wants to store another entry, but token from step 3 is now expired and API call fails
8. User won’t be happy, so me neither

Possible ways to solve:

1. Make the JWT last longer than the current 30 minutes, but that just postpones the issue and opens some security doors
2. Storing users’ input in local storage to restore it later after a token refresh (we also would do that to not loose users’ work)
3. Refresh the token „silently“ in JS without user knowing. Is there a best practice for that?
4. I missed something important and the internet now tells me a better architecture for my application.

Thank you internet!

Comment: I have never used it, so can't help with it, but I know that Keycloak comes with a JavaScript library. Among others, it lets you easily do your option 3 (refreshing the token on background), see https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#updatetoken-minvalidity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re the step 3. In Quarkus 1.5.0 adding `quarkus.oidc.token.refresh-expired=true` will get the ID token refreshed and the user session extended if the refresh grant has succeeded

Comment: Just for reference, it's the property added here: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/c7d37ecc714999b8aefb95d09abe5646ee89582a/extensions/oidc/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/oidc/OidcTenantConfig.java#L639

Answer (score 0):

For such use cases, I tend to prefer the reverse of JWT. I keep the user data in a shared data service (a data grid like Infinispan or Redis). So that this data is keyed by the user and available. I do control the TTL of that data in the shared data service.

It can either be specific to an app, or shared between a small number of apps. It does bring some coupling but so does the JWT property structure.

For Quarkus, there is an Infinispan client integration, a Hazelcast one, mongodb and AWS dynamoDB. And you can bring other libraries.